# Cannot Apply toDateString() to Date in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime

I am running into a problem I'm trying to understand. I am simply trying to convert a date into a more reader-friendly format by using toDateString(). However, in doing so I am getting a "toDateString() is not a function" error.

I can do this, using toString():

```
truncateDate() {
    if (this.employee && this.employee.dob)
    {
        let birthDate = this.employee.dob;
        console.log(birthDate); // 2011-06-12T05:00:00.000Z Prints to console
        console.log(birthDate.toString());
    }
}
```

But I cannot do toDateString():

```
truncateDate() {
    if (this.employee && this.employee.dob)
    {
        let birthDate = this.employee.dob;
        console.log(birthDate); // 2011-06-12T05:00:00.000Z Prints to console
        console.log(birthDate.toDateString());
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: because birthDate is not a Date type object

Comment: You sure that `this.employee.dob` is a Date object? What does `this.employee.dob.constructor` return?

Comment: `console.log(typeof(birthDate))`, it is probably a string.

Comment: @Ademo try `new Date(birthDate).toDateString()`

Comment: @MikeCorcoran, thanks, this is true. To my surprise after running the "typeof" check, it's a string.

Comment: Many thanks, @Alex and others. The issue was that the value is a string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Convert the string to Date Object then you will be able to use that function.
Here is MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString

```js
this.employee={}
this.employee.dob='1/2/2018'
let birthDate = this.employee.dob;
console.log(birthDate);
console.log(new Date(birthDate).toDateString());

//
```

Comment: Yup, this was indeed the issue - the original value was of type string. I will remember to run the typeof check more often if I run into this kind of thing again.